# Line spacing help, expl3

Tags: expl3, parskip, vspace

I have a macro `makeentry` which I cannot get to behave as I would expect. Its pretty simple, it takes previously input user data and formats it. However I cannot get the macro to respect my wishes for `parskips` and `vspaces` properly. There are some very strange interactions going on which I must be overlooking. Not only is the `parskip` not happening, but the `vspace` is in the wrong spot!

In this mwe I have provided a two column comparison with the macro formatted text on the left, and the manual formatted (and expected output) on the right.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}%allows more color options. 

\ExplSyntaxOn
%*******************************************tokenlists***************************************************%
\tl_new:N \itemname_mwe%used to store the name
\tl_new:N \itemdescr_mwe%used to store the description
\tl_new:N \itemnote_mwe%used to store a note

%********************************Global_variable_storage_commands****************************************%
\NewDocumentCommand{\name}{s+m} {%set command for names
    \tl_set:Nn \itemname_mwe {#2}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\descr}{s+m} {%set command for descriptions
    \tl_set:Nn \itemdescr_mwe {#2}
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\note}{s+m} {%set command for notes
    \tl_set:Nn \itemnote_mwe {#2}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\makeentry}{}{
    \tl_if_empty:NF \itemname_mwe {%
        {\color{black}\sffamily\bfseries \tl_use:N \itemname_mwe}\\
    }
    \tl_if_empty:NF \itemdescr_mwe {%
        \textit{\tl_use:N \itemdescr_mwe}\\ 
    }
    \tl_if_empty:NF \itemnote_mwe {%
        \vspace{15pt plus 2.0pt}
        \tl_use:N \itemnote_mwe\\
    }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\twocolumn
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{5pt plus 2.0pt}



\name{Mount Baker}
\descr{Mount Baker, also known as Koma Kulshan or simply Kulshan, is a 10,781 ft active glacier-covered andesitic stratovolcano in the Cascade Volcanic Arc and the North Cascades of Washington in the United States. Mount Baker has the second-most thermally active crater in the Cascade Range after Mount St. Helens.}

\note{Mount Baker was well known to indigenous peoples of the Pacific Northwest. Indigenous names for the mountain include Koma Kulshan or Kulshan. In 1790, Manuel Quimper of the Spanish Navy set sail from Nootka, a temporary settlement on Vancouver Island, with orders to explore the newly discovered Strait of Juan de Fuca.}

\makeentry

\vfill\break

{\color{black}\sffamily\bfseries Mount Baker}\\
{\itshape Mount Baker, also known as Koma Kulshan or simply Kulshan, is a 10,781 ft active glacier-covered andesitic stratovolcano in the Cascade Volcanic Arc and the North Cascades of Washington in the United States. Mount Baker has the second-most thermally active crater in the Cascade Range after Mount St. Helens.}

\vspace{15pt plus 2.0pt}

{\upshape Mount Baker was well known to indigenous peoples of the Pacific Northwest. Indigenous names for the mountain include Koma Kulshan or Kulshan. In 1790, Manuel Quimper of the Spanish Navy set sail from Nootka, a temporary settlement on Vancouver Island, with orders to explore the newly discovered Strait of Juan de Fuca.}

\end{document}
```

Comment: don't use ``\\`` to separate paragraphs. Use `\par`.

Comment: Thank you. I knew I was forgetting something simple.